# Convert WolframAlpha output to $\LaTeX$

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

I am using WolframAlpha app on my iPad and would like to confirm that there is no way to convert its output to $\LaTeX$ form?

It would be nice to have this feature so as to copy it to Stack Exchange for questions.
I do not have Wolfram Mathematica

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following. Once you get the output in Wolfram Alpha web page, say you have typed `solve y'+x=0`, then in the output window, hover the mouse there, and select `plain text` option

[image]

Then in the window which opens, select `continue in computable notebook`

[image]

Then a Wolfram Alpha notebook now opens showing the commands it used to generate the output on the web page. Like this

[image]

The commands are not evaluated. To evaluate them, hit the **enter** key in the first cell. This will now generate the output you saw at the Wolfram web page.

Then below the output cell, now type the command `TeXForm[%]` to generate the Latex, like this

[image]

Then copy the Latex to clipboard and paste the latex to your Latex editor.

Comment: Strange...I get output as "0.01 TeXForm"

Comment: @user9106985 did you evaluate the CELL and type `TeXForm[%]` in new cell below it?

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the plain text and use http://asciimath.org/ to convert it to MathML, and then on https://npm.runkit.com you can do:

```
const Mathml2latex = require('mathml-to-latex');

const mathml = `
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
.
.
.
</math>
      `;
 
Mathml2latex.convert(mathml);
```

And then run it

[image]

Or alternatively paste it to a text file, save as `mathml.xml`, download the [XSLT MathML library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xsltml/), download an XSLT processor like [saxon](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/) on the XML file, and then put it all in the same folder and execute:

### [image]

Alternatively you can sign up at https://www.wolframcloud.com and then go to  https://www.wolframcloud.com and create a new notebook and then paste in the wolfram language code for the computation and then press shift enter and then type in `TeXForm[%]` and then shift enter as Nasser says.

[image]